# theming user profile with "User Field Privacy" - but no "Privacy" available

Tags: entities, users

My setup is like this: multiple additional user fields (not using profile2) and the module "[User Field Privacy](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_privacy)" is enabled.

I am currently theming user profile pages through a preprocess function and the corresponding  user-profile.tpl.php… Now I have some fields that should be visible to some roles, but hidden to others. I trigger this through the module  "User Field Privacy". Looking for variables in the devel dump does not bring anything for "User Field Privacy" .

```
 [field_telefon] => Array
         (
           [und] => Array
              (
                [0] => Array
                   (
                     [value] => +01 234 567 890
                     [format] => 
                     [safe_value] => +01 234 567 890
                    )

               )

          )
```

When not theming through preprocess and .tpl, everything is fine – the fields marked *hidden* are actually hidden from regular and anonymous users, but shown to users with the appropriate permission.

How/where can I find the "marker" or "flag" for the User Field Privacy setting ?

Any pointers, hints and tips welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update/solved: I did solve my problem now with very basic measurements: for each field I wanted to have a 'privat option' for, I added an extra checkbox field ("public/private"). This setup just works fine no need to have "User Field Privacy" installed – at least for me. Hope this might help somebody some day.